# High disk usage with Windows Performance Recorder and sistem.exe

Tags: windows-10, performance-monitor

I have a laptop running Windows 10. Some days ago I installed Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) in order to solve a disk usage problem during startup. I set it to start recording during startup, and it did so. The following day, during startup the laptop was very slow and I noticed a disk usage that was even higher than usual. I found out that the system.exe process (PID 4) was writing tons of data in some files related to WPR:

[image]

One of those files was huge (> 50 GB). I uninstalled Windows Performance Toolkit, which included WPR, and deleted the related entries in the registry. Nevertheless, for some reason, the problem keeps happening. A process called WindowsPerformanceRecorder is executed at startup, the WPR GUI keeps showing up and system.exe keeps writing. I have to type

> WPR -cancel

in the prompt every time in order to stop it.

I found out that, when I uninstalled WPR, it has been removed from the folder *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10*, but not from the folder *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1* (which is where the WindowsPerformanceRecorder process comes from). I tried every solution to disable it at startup but I failed. Also, there are no uninstallation files and I cannot uninstall it from Control Panel or with other softwares like Revo Uninstaller.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: WPR doesn't solve issues, it allow you to debug them. some profiles record to file, compared to memory so you see diskIO. which original issue do you try to solve?

Comment: You are right, I misspoke: I wanted to find out which processes were causing a high disk activity during startup, since I have a 100% disk activity for some minutes after login

Comment: run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures the Disk activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot (this is what you skipped and logger stays on). now analyze the ETL for disk and fileIO: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-45-WPT-File--Registry-Analysis

Answer (score 1):

I solved by myself:

- Computer management, Performance, Data collector sets, Startup event trace sessions, disable the ones related to WPR
- Revo uninstaller, hunter mode, aim the GUI tha keeps appearing at startup, uninstall and scan the registry for the leftovers
- Delete the files in appData